# Console.ReadLine() not keeping console open in C#

Tags: c#, console.readline

I'm learning C# (VS 2012 Professional) and in the following example, the console window isn't staying open even though the `Console.ReadLine()` method is the last instruction in the code block:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testing
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // fahrenheit conversion example
        Console.Write("Enter temp in fahrenheit: ");
        double fahrenheit = Console.Read();
        double celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * (5.0 / 9.0);
        Console.WriteLine("Celsius is: " + celsius);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    }
}
```

Is there an intricacy I am overlooking in the implementation of the `Console.ReadLine()` method or perhaps a conflicting piece of code in the code block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you type the value for the `fahrenheit` variable and then press Return (Enter). 
This will get the value in the Read call and the Enter in the ReadLine.

Change to

```
Console.Write("Enter temp in fahrenheit: ");
double fahrenheit;
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
if(double.TryParse(userInput, out fahrenheit))
{
    double celsius = (fahrenheit - 32.0) * (5.0 / 9.0);
    Console.WriteLine("Celsius is: " + celsius);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Non a valid double value");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Also, the [Console.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx), unlike the [Console.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx), returns a string and thus you need to parse and convert to a double before trying to use it. This could be done with [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) that will return false when the user doesn't type a valid numeric double

Another drawback for Console.Read is that you need to call it in a loop to read all characters typed by the user till the Enter. If you try to convert 12.8 you need a completely different code to go with Console.Read. (Look at the MSDN example in the link above)

Comment: +1 - Beat me to it, Changing the last to `ReadKey`, also works. (was testing although readline is needed for first)

Comment: Double.Parse required `Console.ReadLine()` returns string

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'` raised possibly because a double can't be entered in ReadLine()?  But it can be entered in `Read()`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, well, you are right but then it is better to use Double.TryParse and avoid the exception

Comment: Also simply changing the `ReadLine()` call to `ReadKey()` works.

Comment: Confirmed, using the original code and changing the last `ReadLine()` to `ReadKey()` also allows the console window to stay open.

Comment: Yes, but please read the docs on Console.Read from MSDN (link above). It returns an Integer not a Double and you need a loop to get all the values typed by the user (For example 12.8 requires 4 Console.Read call)

Answer (score 0):

`Console.Read()` "Reads the next character from the standard input stream". This includes the Enter key. It returns an integer so, for Enter, would return 13.

`Console.ReadLine()` "Reads the next line of characters from the standard input stream". This includes the Enter key (the newline character) but this character is discarded. it returns a string.

`Console.ReadKey()` "Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user". That is, it ignores whatever is left in the input stream and waits for the next key-press.

So you might use `Read()` within a loop to read individual characters, stopping when a certain character is read, or use `ReadLine()` to read, and then parse, the complete line entered by the user. But using both `Read()` and `ReadLine()` in the same code can be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Just press Ctrl+F5 to run the code.